# Can I map 2 plaintext letters to 1 ciphertext letter?

Tags: encryption, decryption

Plaintext: "abcd" where P1,P2,P3,P4 map to each corresponding letter.
And C is the ciphertext where C1,C2,C3,C4 map to each corresponding letter.
Keys = (x,y,z)

Can I use the following encryption algorithm? Is there a corresponding decryption algorithm?

```
C1 = xP1 + P2 
C2 = yP2 + zP3
C3 = P4 + zP3
C4 = xP3 + yP4
```

It doesn't seem like I could reverse the encryption algorithm to get the decryption algorithm.

Comment: The functionality requirement; $E_k(D_k(m)) = m$.

Comment: @kelalaka so there should be a 1:1 mapping from E(X) to D(X)? Therefore this encryption algorithm is not legit?

Comment: It is not exactly one to one, There may be more than one ciphertext for a message $m$ and that we want due to the security, however, the decryption must give back to $m$. We could say, the inverse exists!

Comment: @kelalaka since C3 and C4 requires both P3 and P4, we can't get back the exact P3 and P4? can we have multiple plaintext letters to encrypt 1 ciphertext letter?

Comment: I don't know the origin of the question. It may be just a mode of operation... You have 4 equations and 4 unknowns therefore it is solvable by Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: @kelalaka: it is solvable, unless the equations are singular (which it will be for certain keys, e.g. $P1 = P2 = P3 = P4 = 0$

Comment: @poncho I was going to step by step for the OP. Yes, it must be singular, or full rank. etc.